# The accept answer icon

Tags: feature-request

I noticed the accept check mark icon changed a little while ago.

Just an opinion - it looks very similar to the vote up or down button, may be better to make it look different to avoid confusion, especially with non technical people.

For example, in stackoverflow the check mark to accept an answer is very clearly displayed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540975/python-object-type-and-inheritance

thanks!

Comment: You might consider posting an answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126185/1438), where it's more likely the developers will notice.

Comment: Yes, please post to the MSO post Jon pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As that's part of the new Beta theme, we're stuck with it until we graduate and get our own design. That said, I myself don't see a problem with its appearance. Not to mention, if one accidentally accepts an answer, another click will deaccept it and (if done quickly enough) no one will be the wiser.